# Change Fill property of Path control inside ListBox

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a small question, I've created a `ListBox` that only contains 2 items. Each item is a `Path` control that has a `Fill` attribute set to Black.

Now, what I'm trying to do is, change the colour of this Fill attribute when you select one of the items in the listbox... I would think this should be done with a `Style`. But when doing so, the style contains a `ContentPresenter` that maps to the Path and this ContentPresenter has no `Fill` attribute to change through the `IsSelected` trigger!

So in other words, how can I still use a Style that maps the Fill attribute?

My current XAML code of the `Window` in the `WPF` project:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="XAMLPathStyleProblem.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,0,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>                             
                            </Trigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
            <ListBox x:Name="ImageBar" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListBoxItemStyle}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <Path Data="M15.992466,14.680105C20.892824,14.680104 23.97299,17.360288 28.013305,17.360288 31.943504,17.360288 34.333683,14.680104 39.994102,14.680105 44.274425,14.680104 48.804641,17.000391 52.034961,21.0308 41.454162,26.831151 43.174373,41.942682 53.865043,45.983101 52.394974,49.24342 51.694851,50.703518 49.794819,53.583672 47.154625,57.614079 43.424389,62.624561 38.803959,62.664604 34.703705,62.704647 33.643696,59.994431 28.073246,60.024464 22.50292,60.054249 21.342806,62.714657 17.23254,62.674614 12.622241,62.634571 9.0819604,58.104115 6.441766,54.083717 -0.95864094,42.822647 -1.7287129,29.611443 2.8315349,22.590761 6.0717456,17.600301 11.19209,14.680104 15.992466,14.680105z M38.751411,0C39.321331,3.8093758 37.761547,7.538764 35.701835,10.178331 33.502144,12.997869 29.702673,15.197509 26.033186,15.077528 25.373277,11.438125 27.093038,7.6887398 29.172746,5.1591539 31.462427,2.3696117 35.39188,0.23996067 38.751411,0z"
                      Fill="Black" />
            </ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem>
                <Path Data="M32.127438,4.0459317E-05C34.679321,-0.0059787218,51.370113,0.63573532,60.553993,18.050023L60.522991,18.050023 60.543671,18.086075C61.200066,19.24132 68.004066,31.93957 59.575981,47.967091 59.575981,47.967091 51.176838,64.148377 30.558096,63.870453L29.65756,63.847004 29.649204,63.861397C29.644096,63.870198,29.641504,63.874661,29.641504,63.874661L29.638971,63.874695 29.681444,63.800747C30.804413,61.84562,39.865662,46.068413,42.345753,41.710415L42.378082,41.653572 42.392643,41.638874 42.472183,41.501145 42.692501,41.246766C44.087284,39.55642,45.09919,37.538369,45.595421,35.325478L45.613995,35.233231 45.681602,34.931549C45.857914,34.084336,45.977459,33.046578,45.939392,31.839535L45.927822,31.607016 45.927765,31.604247 45.927345,31.597495 45.913135,31.311926 45.901112,31.172703 45.89138,31.015126 45.867527,30.783802 45.865814,30.76396 45.8638,30.747662 45.831325,30.432713C45.783504,30.046782,45.720222,29.665644,45.64212,29.289938L45.605244,29.129017 45.579826,29.001641C45.3101,27.769034 44.871658,26.423209 44.200989,24.977549 43.870582,24.491171 43.539108,24.000555 43.182049,23.514327L42.899601,23.140976 60.287002,18.042616C60.287002,18.042616,39.292564,18.022913,34.351002,18.039915L34.393581,18.050023 34.172077,18.050023C33.849613,18.050023,33.54248,18.050023,33.252323,18.050023L33.158501,18.050023 32.880497,18.023783C32.497307,17.992794 32.109821,17.977 31.718649,17.977 31.350422,17.977 30.985464,17.990992 30.624279,18.018473L30.292705,18.050023 30.278829,18.050023C30.225145,18.050023 30.197481,18.050023 30.197481,18.050023 30.197481,18.050023 30.175093,18.049284 30.131918,18.049599 29.747402,18.052403 27.714258,18.138693 25.166611,19.573328L25.156681,19.579142 25.090729,19.612418C22.198151,21.138638,19.8955,23.632718,18.613605,26.663617L18.496868,26.959704 5.5749997,14.177C5.5749997,14.177,15.021078,30.765849,17.85829,35.692574L17.988001,35.917668 18.035503,36.093228C19.728666,42.05547 25.213291,46.422997 31.718649,46.422997 32.332252,46.422997 32.936783,46.384125 33.529907,46.308712L33.816097,46.268658 29.596954,63.874993 29.542429,63.874833C28.213777,63.865578 13.814976,63.407895 4.1510181,48.093563 4.1510176,48.093563 -5.6624084,32.728032 4.8882693,15.012328L5.3907794,14.192161 5.3934535,14.187385C5.6228327,13.780242 13.109029,0.74591898 31.796461,0.0057129142 31.796461,0.0057133239 31.911178,0.00055203911 32.127438,4.0459317E-05z"
                      Fill="Black" />
            </ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok... found the answer myself!
When changing the Fill value inside the Path control to a binding one, all works as expected!

```
Fill="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using MVVM pattern with MVVM Light Toolkit. Then you should create Collection of data that you want to dispaly on the list. In your case it can be Data and Fill (Color). Then you need to handled Click event and that's all. I have code that provides such feature, so If you want it, please ask.

But in your case (without MVVM Light toolkit) I would rather do sth like this:

```
<Style x:Key="Path" TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
    <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected" Value="True">
             <Setter Property="Fill" Value="YouColor"/>
          </DataTrigger>
          <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}, Path=IsSelected" Value="False">
             <Setter Property="Fill" Value="YouAnotherColor"/>
          </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Best regards.
Mateusz

Comment: Also a good suggestion, but using a Binding to RelativeSource ListBoxItem works

Comment: Yep, definitely :) But as far as i know, you firstly change the foreground color of ListBoxItem and this changes provides changes in Path Fill Color. I think it can be done in one place.

Comment: Yes, that is also true :) but even though I defined the style in my question... with my solution ( was to point out the contentpresenter ) I don't need it anymore and just use the default behaviour of the listbox.